# How to find out the name of Windows system profile?

Tags: c++, windows, postgresql, winapi

I am writing a **Windows Service** that would be work with database using a *system profile* name. For this feature I have a **Postgres SQL Server**.

I want to create **trust  authentication** for Windows *system profile* before I run the service.

For this I'll run some console application that would write needed information like authentication method in ***pg_hba.conf*** file and create role with *system profile* name. By the way, it's very cool that Postgres can identifies other language symbols (not sure about all of them though).

**The problem** is how can I find out ***translated*** name of Windows system profile? Cause each Windows on different languages has different system profile name: *system*, *система*, *sistema* etc.

Comment: "Most services do not need such a high privilege level. If your service does not need these privileges ... consider using the LocalService account or the NetworkService account. " - from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MSalters, yes it's right. Unfortunately I am using `QtService` for my task and its command `-i` is not allow to choose from what user I want to install the service (or maybe I didn't find out this feature). Ofcourse, I can install it from `cmd` via `sc` command but it is not way I want to.

Comment: @MSalters, oh no, my bad. There is a simple way to use another system profile with `NT<...>/<kind>` after `-i` key. But than - problem in their name: Network profile name - PC name and Local profile name - name with space. And I can't register them in Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**So, problem solved with WinAPI:**

```
#include <windows.h>

<...>

static const DWORD MAX_BUFF_SIZE = 256;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY auth = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
PSID pSid = NULL;
SID_NAME_USE use;    
wchar_t buffName[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];    // Here would be name
DWORD buffNameSize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
wchar_t buffDomain[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
DWORD buffDomainSize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;

AllocateAndInitializeSid(&auth, 1, SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pSid);
LookupAccountSid(NULL, pSid, buffName, &buffNameSize, buffDomain, &buffDomainSize, &use);

FreeSid(pSid);

<...>
```

Answer (score 1):

["The name of the account in all locales is **.\LocalSystem.**"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx)